# Rails issue on starting up after successful installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I have already installed rails on my 2 desktop machine through VM's (RedHat Linux) and there was no issue after installation , rails worked perfectly.
This time when I try installing in my Cent-OS server, followed same process but after installation, it is not working.

```
**rails -v** 
**rails s**
```

The above command throws `-bash: rails: command not found` . Had gone through almost al the posts similar about this issue and i found $PATH in .bashrc or .bash_profile seems to be the most commmon issue and many have fixed on making the PATH. I tried all those but still that doesn't fix my issue.

Any rails specialist here could help me out? Need to understand What is making the issue in my case.

```
sh-4.1$ ~]# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc --bindir /app/interpreters/ruby/1.9.3/bin/"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /opt/res/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /root/bin
sh-4.1$ ~]# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
sh-4.1$ ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/opt/res/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
sh-4.1$ ~]# cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
sh-4.1$ ~]

    [sh-4.1$ ~]# pwd
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4/bin
sh-4.1$ ~]# ls
ruby_executable_hooks
[sh-4.1$ ~]# pwd
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4/gems
[sh-4.1$ ~]# ls
actionmailer-4.0.2  activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3  builder-3.1.4  mail-2.5.4              polyglot-0.3.3   railties-4.0.2         thread_safe-0.1.3
actionpack-4.0.2    activesupport-4.0.2                    erubis-2.7.0   mime-types-1.25.1  rack-1.5.2       sprockets-2.10.1       tilt-1.4.1
activemodel-4.0.2   arel-4.0.1                             hike-1.2.3     minitest-4.7.5     rack-test-0.6.2  sprockets-rails-2.0.1  treetop-1.4.15
activerecord-4.0.2  atomic-1.1.14                          i18n-0.6.9     multi_json-1.8.2   rails-4.0.2      thor-0.18.1            tzinfo-0.3.38
[sh-4.1$ ~]# 


 [sh-4.1$ ~]# hash -r
 [sh-4.1$ ~]# echo $GEM_PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global
[sh-4.1$ ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/opt/res/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[sh-4.1$ ~]#
```

Comment: I once had this problem. Logged out when I gave up for a pause and, when I logged back in, got it working - still don't understand why thou =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with ruby 2.1.1p76 and rails 4.0.4 on mint cinnamon.

After installation it worked first time but when i tried rails command after logging out. It said rails is not installed.
Assuming you have rvm, ruby and rails installed, do

```
rvm use ruby --default
```

If it gives an error about ruby use .. do

```
/bin/bash --login
```

and try again

```
rvm use ruby --default
```

and now when you will type rails, it will work

Answer (score 0):

run:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p484@rails_4
gem install rails
rails -v
```

Comment: thanks. But that is not working, i already did the same. Tried once again but still not working.I doubt where rails got installed properly or not. Is there any other to confirm rails files are installed properly? I also checked the gems and bin dir under ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails_4, gems dir have all the pkgs, however under bin i dont how to confirm rails is installed properly. (Added bin and gem dir files in above question)

Comment: run `rvm use 1.9.3-p484@rails_4` and read all the output, it should tell you if there are any problems with your setup

Comment: after i give `rvm use 1.9.3-p484@rails_4`, it shows `Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484 with gemset rails_4`. do you mean the output as anything else? also i would need to know if there any pkg dependencies which would not make rails to run? thanks a lot @mpapis for helping me out !!

Comment: does `hash -r` help? run & add to your question: `echo $GEM_PATH; echo $PATH`

Comment: added GEM_PATH & PATH to the question. `hash -r` just run and no output for that.

Answer (score 0):

Does `ruby -v` show any specific version number? If yes then go to the root of your rails app and do `gem install rails`.

If `ruby -v` does not show any specific version then do `rvm install 1.9.3` (instead of 1.9.3 you can also use 2.0.0 or any other older ones).
Then once the installation completes do `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`.

Note: Do not use `sudo apt-get install rails`, just the gem is enough.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input.. I fixed the issue by re-installing again from the scratch and that worked :)

Comment: Pleased to know it worked out for you. Dont forget to tick mark one of the answers you feel is right so that people know that this post has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed the issue. As i thought, there was something messed up in the installation. I found no rails executable file under gem/bin dir.

Previously my gems/bin has only **ruby_executable_hooks** , since there was no executable file like **rails** (Really i don't know if this was really issue) but I thought to re install rvm & rails once again from scratch.

RVM re-installation:

```
rvm remove ... # take the output of rvm list and do rvm remove for each item in the list
rvm cleanup all
rvm install 2.0.0
```

Updated gem version:

```
gem update --system 2.1.9
```

Installing Rails:

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.2
rails -v
```

So this was i found before and after in gems/bin dir 
**Before ** (when rails was not working even though PATH and al other stuff's were perfect)

```
[sh-4.1$ ~]# pwd
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
[sh-4.1$ ~]# ls
ruby_executable_hooks
```

** After re-installation **

```
[sh-4.1$ ~]# pwd
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
[sh-4.1$ ~]# ls
erubis  rackup  rails  ruby_executable_hooks  sprockets  thor  tilt  tt  update_rubygems
```

Comment: `gem update --system 2.1.9` means you had to use rubygems `2.1.9` you could tell rvm to do that: `rvm install 2.0.0 --rubygems 2.1.9` or `latest-2.1` ... anyway you should try to reproduce this problem with rubygems `2.2.0` and report a bu here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues

Comment: @mpapis : sure, will try to do that and report in github.